# SH скрипт при отключении клиента openvpn

Tags: bash, vpn, openvpn

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при отключении клиента от openvpn сервера вызывался sh скрипт, в который бы передавалось имя пользователя которое ввёл пользователь так как используется только один клиентский конфиг.

```
auth-user-pass-verify /etc/openvpn/verify.sh via-file
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
tmp-dir /etc/openvpn/tmp
dublicate-cn
```

Comment: Не очень понял вопрос, что значит "имя которое ввел пользователь"? На сколько я понимаю, имя при отключении будет равно имени при корректном подключении, а это логин пользователя. Если вышесказанное верно, то мы отлавливаем логин отключившегося пользователя. Правильно ли я понял задачу?

Comment: `down "/путь/к/скрипту`. а в нём уже смотрите, что поступает в переменных окружения. наверняка там присутствует и нужная вам информация.

Comment: судя по [руководству](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/openvpn.8.html) подойдёт либо `common_name`, либо `username`

Comment: @Andrew, вот есть скрипт veify.sh, и в него передаётся логин и пароль который вводит клиент. Так вот, можно ли при отключении клиента вызывать скрипт в который будет передаваться логин клиента ?

Answer (score 0):

@ilya50 Если честно, так глубоко в openvpn не забирался, но из костылей, которые приходят в голову, это парсить `status`, приблизительно так

```
cat /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log | sed -n '4,/ROUTING TABLE/p' | grep -E ",[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\:[[:digit:]]{1,5}"| awk -F ',' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq > connected_now
```

Удалять имена подключенных из такого-же файла сгенеренного 5-10 сек назад и для оставшихся выполнять скрипт отключения.
Вешать эту операцию на демона со `sleep` в те-же 5-10 сек.

Это не законченный скрипт, но если чисто идеи не хватит, допишу полностью.